# How to create my own template?

Tags: graphics, texworks, python

I am currently in the process of making a latex template with the context of each page having an image and under each page there should be a table of values in regards of the image. So I am using python to grab the details of the image and now I have to somehow transfer it to the latex format. I am unable to find much on making your own forms using Jinja or stuff like that so any help would be useful, because I haven't used jinja or latex before and I am googling everything as I am encountering a problem.

Note the data in relation to the images are stored as a dict for example:
`'EXdXLrZXS9Q':  {'make': 'NIKON CORPORATION', 'model': 'NIKON D800', 'exposure_time': '1/500', 'aperture': '3.5', 'focal_length': '50.0', 'iso': 100}`

edit:
THe main question at hand is how do I transfer the data to a latex form from python using jinja, in hopes of making a format of image side by side with another image and under each image there are table of values[image]

Comment: your question isn't very clear, python, jinja, web forms etc are all off topic here, you have tagged your question texworks which is an editor but I don't think you are asking an editor specific question, what is the latex question that you wanted to ask?

Comment: I made the required edit and added a picture of how the latex should look hopefully that clarifies a bit.

Comment: you can ask about the final latex (but that is a very basic page) but how to generate that from jinja would need to be asked on a jinja forum not here/

Comment: but how do I design the latex form to accept the data?             
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\BLOCK{for image in images}
\includegraphics{\VAR{image}}
\BLOCK{endfor}
\end{document}
Thats what I am doing right now but It doesn't seem to work

Comment: latex doesn't have anything resembling a "form" you can do the loop in python or whatever and just write out the latex file corresponding to your images I just posted an answer but it overlapped with your comment and doesn't add anything you don't already know given that comment.

Comment: i dont literally mean form, I just meant latex document

Comment: well as I say if you are writing the data from python just loop through it in python writing out the minipage for each image+data there really is no latex specific thing you need to do

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46652984/python-jinja2-latex-table                         anything like this?

Comment: well quite it would be on topic for stackoverflow not here

Answer (score 0):

The required latex file could be easily be written with any text application from the data you show. You just need to generate something like

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{example-image-a}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
 make:& NIKON CORPORATION\\
 model& NIKON D800\\
 exposure time& 1/500\\
 aperture& 3.5\\
 focal length& 50.0\\
 iso& 100
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}%
%
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{example-image-b}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
 make:& NIKON CORPORATION\\
 model& NIKON D800\\
 exposure time& 1/100\\
 aperture& 4.5\\
 focal length& 100.0\\
 iso& 3000
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thats great but how am I supposed to incorporate the data I got from Jinja. I been on that for a minute can't figure out how to do so.

Comment: as I said originally that would be off topic (I know nothing of jinja, but couldn't really address that here even if I did) I don't understand why you need a web templating engine at all, you said you have the image data in python, python could trivially write out this latex, so what do you want jinja to do? @AlphaDJog