# How to set a minimum amount of space for an image?

Tags: graphics

[image]

Right now the image looks like this,
But what I am trying to do is get the table of values all aligned at the same line so it doesn't change depending on the size of the image.

```
\documentclass[14pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\chead{Cool}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=10cm, height =12cm,keepaspectratio]{image1}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
Title & Value\\
\hline
\hline
 make:& None\\
 model& None\\
 exposure time&None\\
 aperture& None\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=10cm, height =12cm]{image2}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
Title & Value\\
\hline
\hline
 make:& Google\\
 model& Pixel\\
 exposure time&1/2451\\
 aperture& 2.0\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: instead of using two minipages use a two row tabular with images in the first row and captions in the second, then the captions will be aligned for different size images

Comment: are you the same user as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/597501/how-to-create-my-own-template/597508#597508 you could ask the accounts be merged if you are.

Comment: it didn't let me ask any q's idk why so I resorted to this

Comment: THing is there are 10 images that have a similar outline and I have to generate the code dynamically, so I can't do what you said cuz it won't be easy to implement with the template I have.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: if you can generate a minipage you can generate a tabular

Comment: Get rid of `\bigskip` and it then works.